# Modifying JSON response via Flask after_request

Tags: python, json, http, flask

I'm (attempting) to create a RESTlike API via Flask and would like to include the HTTP response code inside the returned json response.  I've found the `flask.jsonify()` very helpful in generating my responses and I can manipulate the response via the `app.after_request` decorator.

The issue I have is that the response data is already serialized by the time I can read it in the function I decorate with `app.after_request` so to insert the `response.status_code` would require de-serializing and re-serializing every request.

I'm very new to flask and am unsure of the 'correct' way to get the status_code into the response, preferably before it gets serialized into a completed response.

Comment: why do you need the response code in the message body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never needed to do something like this myself, but you can probably do this by subclassing the `Response` class.

Let's say you create a `JSONResponse` class as a subclass of `Response`. The constructor of this class takes the same arguments as the parent class, but instead of a string for the body it takes a dictionary.

So you do not call `jsonify()` at this point, just pass the dictionary with the data into the `JSONResponse` object. The response object takes the dictionary and stores it aside in a member variable, and then calls the parent response class and sets an empty response body for now.

I think this will fool Flask into thinking the response is valid.

When you get to the `after_request` handler you have access to the response object, so you can get the dictionary, still in its native form, and make any modifications you want.

The `JSONResponse` class has a method that is called, say, `render()` that you call when you are done modifying the dictionary. This method calls `jsonify()` on the final version of the data and updates the response body in the parent class.